# Make edges of SKSpriteNode look smooth after rotation

Tags: rotation, sprite-kit, antialiasing, skspritenode

I create a SKSpriteNode like that:

```
var shape:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(sizeOfShape), CGFloat(sizeOfShape)))
```

How can I achieve, that a SKSpriteNode has still smooth edges, after I've rotated it.

Currently, it looks like that:

[image]

As you see, the edges are jagged.

Comment: unless apple changed this in ios 8 you can't enable antialiasing in sprite kit

Comment: @LearnCocos2D But is there a way to do that with a SKTexture? I've already added an imageset of a rect.