# iOS: How I can make edges of sprite smooth when it is rotated?

Tags: ios, rotation, sprite-kit, sprite, antialiasing

I am making a simple sprite kit game. When I rotate my sprite the edges are jagged. I try texture images and image assets but the results are all the same. 
Here is my code with filtering mode:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imagedNamed: "textureName")
sprite.texture!.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest // Also Try .Linear
```

Changing the sprite's size to its original value or a smaller scale, result does not change.

Is it possible to use antialiased property for sprite nodes ? 
Is there any suggestion? Similar problem on this link:

[Make edges of SKSpriteNode look smooth after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532760/make-edges-of-skspritenode-look-smooth-after-rotation)

Comment: I'm assuming you're testing this on a device right?

Comment: I tested both but results are same.